# Access enum from another class

Tags: java, enums

I am new to Java and I am struggling to get my Enumeration to work. I am working in BlueJ and I have 2 classes (trying to build a game of solitaire). my first class is called Card and inside this class I have an enumeration called Suit. My other class is Deck and I am trying to call the enumeration from this class. My problem is in the for loop for deck where I have declared Suit suit. It does not recognize the class Suit.

My code is below, if anyone can tell what I am doing wrong... it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
public class Deck
{

private Bag<Card> cardBag = new Bag<Card>();

public Deck()
{
  for(Suit suit : Suit.values())
     {
         Card card= new Card (suit, 5);
     }
 }
```

//

```
public class Card
{
public enum Suit
{
    H, S, C, D
}

private Suit suit;
private int valueOfCard;

public static final int ACE = 1;
public static final int JACK = 11;
public static final int QUEEN = 12;
public static final int KING = 13;

public Card(int valueOfCard, Suit suit)
{
    this.valueOfCard= valueOfCard;
    this.suit=suit;
}
}
```

Comment: `enum` and `enumeration` are not the same thing.

Comment: For future reference, please include the exact compiler error in your quesiton.

Comment: @RohitJain Oh... sorry I did not know. What is the difference if I may ask?

Comment: @AlexG.. There is a huge one. `enum` is just a type used to represent enumerated constants. `Enumeration` is an interface (an outdated one) used to iterate over some collections. `Enumeration` has been replaced by `Iterator` now.

Comment: Thank you for the brief explanation. I will look at it more in detail on my own. +1

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are at least two possible solutions here:

1. Place the `Suit` enumeration in its own file.
2. Access `Suit` with its fully qualified name in other classes. That is use `Card.Suit`, rather than just `Suit`.

Comment: The most helpful answer :) Thanks !